# WPF MainWindow to display other pages

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am trying to create a Main Window that will have a Header for navigation/buttons, and a footer for displaying information.
(similar to the top and bottom bars on StackOverflow.com)

[image: Example of how the header and footer stay in one place, while the middle section handles displaying the desired page]

What is the best way to make the Main Window function as a container that could display any page in between the header/footer?

Comment: When I faced this problem,  we used big `TabControl` with hiden tabs for this behaviour.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would create a 3 row `Grid`, with the center item being a `ContentControl`.  Bind it to a `CurrentPage` property on your view model.

Create a Base `Page` class, and subclass it for each page of data you want to display.  This subclass is also the viewmodel for each individual page.

Add a `DataTemplate` for each subclass of `Page` for the `ContentControl` to use, making sure to specify the `Type` attribute (This is what physically attaches the page type to the UI based on the `CurrentPage` property).  The content of the `DataTemplate` should be a `UserControl` that contains the UI for each page type.

Now when you want to change pages, just set CurrentPage to an instance of the page you want, and it will automatically change.

This pattern will keep each page's UI separate from all the other, and gives them a strong view model (the `Page` subclass).  It allows for super easy changing of pages. and follows the MVVM pattern nicely.  You can even load all your pages in to a list that you present to the user. With a little more binding the user selecting a page can flow right in to the page change behavior with very little work.

Answer (score -2):

create a page with 3 rows.  The top row being a height of 'auto' the middle row being of height '*' and the bottom row being height 'auto' as well.  The top and bottom row will take up as much room needed for the header and footer and the middle row will take up the rest of the room.

Answer (score -2):

You can use a Grid

```
<Grid >
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
 <local:TopPage Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" />
 <local:MidPage Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" />
 <local:BottomPage Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" />
 </Grid>
```